# Override default keydown event in VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, preventdefault

Been trying to search around for the most efficient way to override a default keydown event in VanillaJS. In my case specifically, I'm trying to override the default event of the "backspace" key and give it the functionality of a left-arrow key.

I figured out how to use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the default event from happening, with this code:

```
document.querySelector(/* Target selector */).onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(event) {
    let which = event.which;
    let keyCode = event.keyCode;
    let charCode = event.charCode;
    if(which == 8 || keyCode == 8 || charCode == 8) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

But, I can't seem to assign a new event. I've been working with something along these lines, but I have a feeling I'm way off:

```
document.querySelector('#blank-page').onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(event) {
    let which = event.which;
    let keyCode = event.keyCode;
    let charCode = event.charCode;
    if(which == 8 || keyCode == 8 || charCode == 8) {
        which == 37;
        keyCode == 37;
        charCode == 37;
    }
}
```

Does `createEvent()` possibly come into play here?

Comment: Nevermind. I may have answered my own question. I'm realizing that all the event properties in my code are read-only. Might have to go back to the drawing board to find another work-around.

Comment: Check out [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be everything you need but you can use `dispatchEvent` on the element you want to trigger the event.

You could use it as follows:

## JavaScript

```
window.onload = function(){
   document.querySelector('#my-input').onkeydown = checkKey;
}


function checkKey(event) {
    console.log(event);
    let which = event.which;
    let keyCode = event.keyCode;
    let charCode = event.charCode;

    if(which == 8 || keyCode == 8 || charCode == 8) {
        console.log(event.target);
        //dispatch a keydown event on the input element where the Backspace key was pressed. 
        event.target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'keyCode': 37, 'key': 'ArrowLeft', 'code': 'ArrowLeft'})); 
    }else if(keyCode == 37){
        //Added this if statement to check that the ArrowLeft keydown event was dispatched. 
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

## HTML

```
 <input type="text" value="" id="my-input" name="my-input">
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Still doesn't seem to want to change the key, though.

Comment: @GeoffGeorge No probs. Good luck with it :)